# Passing State data to other component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, react-props, react-component

I currently have a  child component **MoodCard** which is being rendered in parent component **MoodPage**.

I have a State Hook in the parent component `const [isHover, setIsHover] = useState(false)` which toggles between true or false when the **MoodCard** is hovered over.

In the **MoodCard** component, I have a conditional `{isHover && ( <div className="play-button-container"> <i className="fas fa-play"></i> </div>)}` which is suppose to display an icon on the **MoodCard** if `isHover` is set to true.

However I need to pass this `isHover` over to the **MoodCard** component so it works in the conditional.

The error I'm getting is:  **'isHover' is not defined  no-undef**. I've tried passing it as props but I don't think I have the right idea on how to do so.

**Sidenote:** I need this to be an individual behaviour for each rendered MoodCard. So would it be better to put this logic in the mapped MoodCard component instances?

*Here is the full code:*

**MoodCard.js**

```
import "./MoodCard.scss";
import MoodPage from "../pages/MoodPage";

export default function MoodCard(props) {
  return (
    <button
      className="mood-card"
      onClick={props.onClick}
      onMouseEnter={props.onMouseEnter}
      onMouseLeave={props.onMouseLeave}
    >
      <figure
        style={{ backgroundImage: `url('${props.backgroundImage}')` }}
      ></figure>
      <h1>{props.name}</h1>
      {isHover && (
        <div className="play-button-container">
          <i className="fas fa-play"></i>
        </div>
      )}
    </button>
  );
}
```

**MoodPage.js**

```
const MoodCardInfo = [
  {
    name: "Rain",
    image: "https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/164284.jpg",
    sound: rain,
  },

  {
    name: "Ocean Waves",
    image: "https://wallpapercave.com/wp/wp2544960.jpg",
    sound: ocean,
  },

  {
    name: "Thunder",
    image: "https://wallpapercave.com/wp/wp2544960.jpg",
    sound: "thunder",
  },
];

export default function MoodPage() {
  const [isHover, setIsHover] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(isHover);
  });

  return (
    <>
          <section className="mood-row">
            {MoodCardInfo.map((info) => (
              <>
                <MoodCard
                  name={info.name}
                  backgroundImage={info.image}
                  onClick={() => setCurrentSound(info.sound)}
                  onMouseEnter={() => setIsHover(true)}
                  onMouseLeave={() => setIsHover(false)}
                />
              </>
            ))}
          </section>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: can you provide sandbox.io  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just do it like this:

```
<section className="mood-row">
            {MoodCardInfo.map((info) => (
              <>
                <MoodCard
                  name={info.name}
                  backgroundImage={info.image}
                  onClick={() => setCurrentSound(info.sound)}
                  onMouseEnter={() => setIsHover(true)}
                  onMouseLeave={() => setIsHover(false)}
                  isHover={isHover}
                />
              </>
            ))}
          </section>

////then you need to do this:

export default function MoodCard(props) {
  return (
    <button
      className="mood-card"
      onClick={props.onClick}
      onMouseEnter={props.onMouseEnter}
      onMouseLeave={props.onMouseLeave}
    >
      <figure
        style={{ backgroundImage: `url('${props.backgroundImage}')` }}
      ></figure>
      <h1>{props.name}</h1>
      {props.isHover && (
        <div className="play-button-container">
          <i className="fas fa-play"></i>
        </div>
      )}
    </button>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works to show the icon on hover. But now it shows on all components instead of the specific one hovered. Any ideas?

Comment: that's because you have passed only one state for all components. if you want to show hover on a specific component, just pass different states for each component.

Comment: and please mark the answer useful and Tick

Comment: Have marked as useful but not tick. As part of the problem is to only show icon on specific component that's hovered which wasn't demonstrated in reply

Comment: it was ticked you have removed it back by clicking it again. just click it once

Comment: and have you solved your problem?

Comment: Not yet. Still unsure on how to pass different states for each component

Comment: just like this, I'm showing you

Comment: take different states like: const [button1, setButton1] = useState(false);   const [button2, setButton2] = useState(false);   const [button3, setButton3] = useState(false)  etc...    OR just take one state with object of states like:     const [buttons, setButtons] = useState({button1: false, button2: false, button3: false})

Comment: just try this, if your problem solved okay if not send me your code i will fix it

Answer (score 0):

you can use an `id` for each `card info` as follow:

```
const MoodCardInfo = [
  {
    name: "Rain",
    image: "https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/164284.jpg",
    sound: rain, 
    id:0
  },

  {
    name: "Ocean Waves",
    image: "https://wallpapercave.com/wp/wp2544960.jpg",
    sound: ocean,
    id:1
  },

  {
    name: "Thunder",
    image: "https://wallpapercave.com/wp/wp2544960.jpg",
    sound: "thunder",
    id:2
  },
];
```

then instead of enabling `isHover` as a boolean, set the id of the hovered item

```
const [hoverId, setHoverId] = useState(-1);
```

and finally, pass it to the child component:

```
<MoodCard
                  name={info.name}
                  backgroundImage={info.image}
                  cardId={info.id}
                  hoverId = {hoverId}
                  onClick={() => setCurrentSound(info.sound)}
                  onMouseEnter={() => setHoverId(true)}
                  onMouseLeave={() => setHoverId(-1)}
                />
```

I am not sure that what you want to do in the child component, but you can compare the card id with the `hoverId` and if their equal, you can do whatever you want.
also, having `useEffect` without any condition is not correct, use this instead:

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(isHover);
  }, [hoverId]);
```

Comment: There is an icon in my MoodCard component that I'm trying to render when MoodCard is hovered